# How to connect to VPN without disconnecting all PuTTY sessions? (Windows 11)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, putty

I am currently using Cisco AnyConnect to get into my work VPN. Whenever I connect or disconnect, it disconnects all my PuTTY sessions. Would it be possible to, for example, selectively route my PuTTY traffic so that it only goes through the VPN if that's enabled? If that's impossible with AnyConnect, is there perhaps another VPN client where it would be possible?

Comment: Split tunneling may offer this. Your work may define how VPN works though. What research have you done and what have you tried? If this is s work computer you must ask your employer about this: we cannot and will not assist where your IT are responsible.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like VPN split tunneling.  I've done this before in Shrew Soft VPN client, but I'm not sure if you have all the permissions to do so for Cisco AnyConnect if you don't have admin rights (and even if you do, your corporate policy may not let you edit the VPN config). You could try reading through this guide to see if it's possible: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/119006-configure-anyconnect-00.html

[image: Split Tunneling]